# How may times can you charge during a combat?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, charge

I have quite a silly question (sorry for that): how may times can you charge during a combat in DnD 3.5?

I remember seeing somewhere that you can do it only once, but i cannot find that source again.
Moreover this seems quite restrictive and does not make much sense, so i'd be gladly proven wrong.

thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can charge as many times as you want, provided you're in the right conditions (enough distance, no obstacles in your path) and you have enough time to do the action (with a *Belt of Battle* or on a high-level factotum you could do it even twice in a round).

The Dire Charge epic feat, the Catfolk Pounce feat from Races of the Wild and the Pounce special attack from some 3.0 monsters can only be used during the first round of combat. Maybe your "source" is based on one of these.

Comment: It's the Dire Charge epic feat that can only be used during the first round. The Catfolk Pounce feat (Races of the Wild) is similar. The general Pounce Special Ability has no such restriction.

Answer (score 17):

You can charge anytime you want providing you see your ennemy and there is a practicable 10-feet long straight path between you two.

[D20SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#charge) says :

> You must move before your attack, not after. You must move at least 10 feet (2 squares) and may move up to double your speed directly toward the designated opponent.
>
> You must have a clear path toward the opponent, and nothing can hinder your movement (such as difficult terrain or obstacles). Here’s what it means to have a clear path. First, you must move to the closest space from which you can attack the opponent. (If this space is occupied or otherwise blocked, you can’t charge.) Second, if any line from your starting space to the ending space passes through a square that blocks movement, slows movement, or contains a creature (even an ally), you can’t charge. (Helpless creatures don’t stop a charge.)
>
> If you don’t have line of sight to the opponent at the start of your turn, you can’t charge that opponent.

About the charge, it also says on the [Fleet of Foot feat](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineAbilitiesFeats.htm#fleetOfFoot) :

> Without this feat, you can run or charge only in a straight line.

Answer (score 6):

Charge is a full-round action, so you can only do it once *per turn*. You can do it as many times as you want each combat.

Answer (score 1):

RAW, you can charge as often as you can manage the right setup for it (no rough terrain and a target that's far enough away being the main points to watch for). Charge is often referred to as a once-per-battle thing because, as a practical matter, it's rarely feasible to set this up over and over in a fight. Usually, charge is used to close with an opponent, and once you've closed with them, you then do full-attacks or the like unless they flee (then you might do another charge as you chase them down).

Answer (score 0):

You can charge whenever circumstances permit a charge. To charge a character must move in a straight line, and must move at least 10'.  This is significant because if an enemy with equal or more speed than yourself closes with you, you generally have the choice between taking no more than a 5' step (subjecting yourself to a full melee attack) or moving more than 5', subjecting yourself to a charge.  A third option, actually running away out of charge range, is possible but carries large risks as you loseboth your attack ability and your Dex bonuses.

Once you get into the middle levels, this becomes a huge tactical decision and depends strongly on the enemy you are facing.  When facing an enemy wielding multiple light weapons, it is often better to move away every turn, even subjecting yourself to both a charge and an attack of opportunity than it would be to face a full attack, especially if you can avoid the AoO by tumbling or some other means.  But this can backfire -- a multi-attacker who can use skirmish damage, or who has a feat like Powerful Charge, can be as dangerous or more when charging as when full-attacking.